# Chart display not same in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reporting-services-2012

I develop my report using SSRS. I want to repeat chart per project.
I use `list` and insert `chart` in list. When I preview report I get this

[image]

I want to display Chart same (same size ) on first Chart

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the rectangle to contain chart. Put the rectangle into the list and make enough space for this rectangle. It supposed to some margin and space setting causing this size issue.